# Helm 'Error: error installing: namespaces "{username}" not found'

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm using Minikube to tinker with Helm.

I understand [Helm installs tiller in the `kube-system` namespace by default](https://helm.sh/docs/install/#easy-in-cluster-installation):

> The easiest way to install `tiller` into the cluster is simply to run
>   `helm init`...
>   Once it connects, it will install `tiller` into the `kube-system`
>   namespace.

But instead it's trying to install tiller in a namespace named after me:

```
$ ~/bin/minikube start
* minikube v1.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04
* Tip: Use 'minikube start -p ' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
* Starting existing virtualbox VM for "minikube" ...
* Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.0 on Docker 18.09.9 ...
* Relaunching Kubernetes using kubeadm ...
* Waiting for: apiserver proxy etcd scheduler controller dns
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
$ helm init
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/mcrenshaw/.helm.
Error: error installing: namespaces "mcrenshaw" not found
$
```

I can specify the tiller namespace, but then I have to specify it in every subsequent use of `helm`.

```
$ helm init --tiller-namespace=kube-system
$HELM_HOME has been configured at /home/mcrenshaw/.helm.

Tiller (the Helm server-side component) has been installed into your Kubernetes Cluster.

Please note: by default, Tiller is deployed with an insecure 'allow unauthenticated users' policy.
To prevent this, run `helm init` with the --tiller-tls-verify flag.
For more information on securing your installation see: https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#securing-your-helm-installation
$ helm upgrade --install some-thing .
Error: could not find tiller
$ helm upgrade --install some-thing . --tiller-namespace=kube-system
Release "some-thing" does not exist. Installing it now.
```

I *suppose* specifying the namespace in each command is fine. But it feels incorrect. Have I done something to corrupt my Helm config?

**Update:**

Per Eduardo's request, here's my helm version:

```
$ helm version --tiller-namespace=kube-system
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.15.0", GitCommit:"c2440264ca6c078a06e088a838b0476d2fc14750", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.15.0", GitCommit:"c2440264ca6c078a06e088a838b0476d2fc14750", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: Can you share which `helm version` are you using?

Comment: @EduardoBaitello sure! Question updated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem using exactly the same versions of minikube/helm/k8s/ubuntu, and just running `helm init` installed the tiller on `kube-system` namespace without problems. Can you check if by any chance do you have a env var [`$TILLER-NAMESPACE`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#synopsis) set? (`printenv TILLER-NAMESPACE`). If so, the env var could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for testing it! `printenv TILLER-NAMESPACE` returns no output. I ran `printenv HOME` as a sanity check, and it returns my home directory.

Comment: As far as I can tell, command line arg and environment variables are the only way to set the tiller namespace.  :-/

Comment: Can you provide information with `kubectl get pods -o wide -A | grep tiller` and information about how You installed helm ?

Comment: @jt97 thanks for your willingness to help - just figured it out! The env variable has an underscore instead of a hyphen and was indeed set to "mcrenshaw". `unset TILLER_NAMESPACE` solved the issue!

Comment: @EduardoBaitello if you'd like to convert your comment to an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Too bad that the env name is wrongly documented on the helm docs webpage ...Sure, I'll answer for future reference

Comment: @EduardoBaitello thanks! If you can find the erroneous doc, I'll enter an issue. [Using Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#easy-in-cluster-installation) at least seems to have it right.

Comment: I referenced [here](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#synopsis), on the `Environment` section all variables are separated by hyphens :(

Comment: @EduardoBaitello yikes. [Issue submitted](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6732). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of setting the Tiller default namespace:

1. Using the `--tiller-namespace` flag (as you are already using).
2. By setting the `$TILLER_NAMESPACE` environment variable.

The flag configuration takes precedence over the environment config. You probably have this environment variable set (you can check with `printenv TILLER_NAMESPACE`). If so, `unset` it and the further `helm` commands should point properly to `kube-system` namespace.